# Possible to avoid elevated privileges to read text files in my app's Program Files folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, wix, uac

I have a WPF app that's installed using a WiX installer. I'm writing all application data to an AppData folder -- which works fine (well, more or less). The installer needs elevated permissions (to write into Program Files, I guess?).

There are a couple of text files packaged with the app that it needs to read. I currently have them in the same folder in Program Files as the .exe, but the app can't read them unless I Run As Administrator.

Here's the code:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        . . .
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way around this, to avoid the need to Run As Admin, *short of changing the installer to put the files in AppData*?

Comment: So long as you don't need elevated privileges to access the file, you could try reading it as read-only.

Comment: Can you show the code that opens the file, and the error message you get when the app tries to open the file?

Comment: Simply reading from that place does not require elevated permissions. Did you check the mode you use to open that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try changing the permission for the file:

```
<File Id="file.txt" 
      Name="file.txt" 
      Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetDir)file.txt">
  <Permission GenericAll="yes" User="Everyone"/>
</File>
```

Comment: Isn't this a security hole?

Comment: That fixed it; thanks. I don't understand why the file isn't readable by default, though.

Comment: You are welcome! Regarding the read problem, , although I didn't test it yet, try using `new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);`.

Comment: Very interesting! It turns out that the default is `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, not `FileAccess.Read` as I assumed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Best option would probably be to tell wix to make a copy of files in App Data Folder:

```
<Directory Id="AppDataFolder" Name="AppDataFolder">
  <Directory Id="appFolder" Name="xx">
    <Component Id="component" Guid="...">
      <File Id="file.txt" Name="file.txt" KeyPath="yes" Source="Assets\file.txt" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize I can do that as a last resort. My question was whether there's an alternative.